# can i connect a stabilizer to petrol generator?

Tags: generator

My generator repairer said that connecting a stabilizer to a petrol generator(***1kva***) would damage its coil. I would like to know if that is true for every other generator with higher ***kVAs***.
Thanks.

Comment: What "stabilizer"? A flexible mount and shock absorber to dampen vibration? These tend to be tuned to the mass involved and the frequency of vibration.

Comment: Think stabilizer is more of an electric/electronic device to stabilize power flow.  My first generator it was suggested to plug in a lamp/light first before using electronics.

Comment: By "stabilizer", do you mean inverter?

Comment: Can you give us a reference to a specific stabilizer so those of us who aren't familiar with them can do a bit of research? I'm not sure what it is or what it's intended to do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Voltage stabilizer.